# PHP library to access Sun Java Calendar Server using WCAP Protocol

Tags: php, calendar

Does anyone know a working library to access a Sun Java Calendar Server using WCAP server in PHP?

I have already tried to work with this library : http://code.google.com/p/php-wcap-client/ but it seems not working. I have spent a few hours trying to debugging it but I haven't managed to.

If someone knows a good way to access this kind of server in PHP, please let me know.

Thank you for your help.
Regards,
Jonathan